# flex and bison: how to recognize an array

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm playing with bison and flex to understand the way how interpreters work. I've already done several things like range (`{INT:INT}` or `{INT:INT:INT}`), strings ({string"here comes any text"}), etc., but I can't decide which should be right way to help bison understand if user entered array in form `[INT, INT, ID, ID, INT, ..., INT, ID, ID...]`?

The first what comes in mind is to use flex keyword `BEGIN` and then look till the end of line, but that seems to stupid since you need a lot of stuff like to understand if next member is INT or ID, and it is not such good way. What can I do else? I'd rather prefer to do it with bison, but I don't know how to make bison look recursive between `[` and `]` to grab all what they contain. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know how to construct an LR(1) Context Free Grammar to recognize such an array?  Or is your problem how to convert it to a format that Bison understands?

Comment: Don't know. Probably you can recommend some books or links to read?

Comment: The Cinderella Book: Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation.  The 4 editions (including the "0th") are apparently different in approach to a certain degree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Automata_Theory,_Languages,_and_Computation -- I am not certain, but I think that covers CFGs and LR(1) grammars etc, if possibly from a too-abstract angle.  Do you have much formal computer science theory in your background?

Comment: @Yakk: no, I don't have it at all, since I'm linguist. :-)

Comment: @DeadMG, do you have an alternate text to suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple- just make a recursive rule.

```
expr :- INT | ID;
array_expr :- array_expr expr | expr;
array :- '[' array_expr ']';
```

It's been a while since I did Bison, but that should be pretty close to correct.

Comment: It has been a while since I constructed an LR(1) grammar, but for some reason I think `array_expr :- epsilon | array_expr expr` is better.  This both allows for empty arrays, and the logic to figure out which rule to follow might be easier: but it has been a decade since I did this last!

Comment: Oh, and epsilon is the traditional name for the "matches the empty string" token.  Not sure how to express that in `Bison`ese.

Comment: @Yakk: in `bison`, `epsilon` is just an empty list of tokens (i.e. whitespace), but it's traditional to write it as `/* empty */` which is more visible for human beings. In general, if you do use an epsilon-rule, you can avoid a lot of trouble by using right-recursion instead of left-recursion, but in this case `expr` unambiguously starts with a token so there is no problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works! May be you even know how to get elements? I know that first element is $1, second is $2, etc., but is it possible to figure out how much elements we have and what are they?